# PyQt: crash on double inheritance from QWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget

The following problem happens with PyQt5, Qt 5.9.6.

I want to generate modal dialog class (`Dialog`) based on another class (`UserForm`). But if `UserForm` already inherits from `QWidget` then my script raises exception

> 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'exec_'

or just crashes silently or crashes with a message in console:

> QDialog::exec: Recursive call detected

MRO looks exactly the same if `UserForm` is inherited from QWidget or not:

```
(<class '__main__.Dialog'>, <class '__main__.UserForm'>, <class
'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QDialog'>, <class 'PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget'>, <class
'PyQt5.QtCore.QObject'>, <class 'sip.wrapper'>, <class
'PyQt5.QtGui.QPaintDevice'>, <class 'sip.simplewrapper'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

class UserForm(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    pass

# class Dialog(UserForm, QtWidgets.QDialog):
#     pass
Dialog = type("Dialog", (UserForm, QtWidgets.QDialog), {})

print(Dialog.__mro__)
Dialog().exec_()
```

I've also tried to run this code with PySide2, Qt 5.12 and it works without issues. Does it mean that there's some bug in PyQt?

Answer (score 2):

On the contrary, it is a bug of PySide2 since it contradicts the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first):

> **Multiple Inheritance Requires QObject to Be First**
>
> If you are using
> multiple inheritance, moc assumes that the first inherited class is a
> subclass of QObject. Also, be sure that only the first inherited class
> is a QObject.

If the behavior described in the previous part is considered then the Dialog class should only take into account UserForm and not QDialog so Dialog should not have the exec_() method since only the classes that inherit from QDialog can have it.

- In Qt you should not inherit from 2 QObject, only supports mixins (QObject + not QObject) <sup>(1)(2)</sup>.
- If it is a mixin then the first must be the QObject.

And that's the pattern that pyuic to inherit:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# or
# from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 240, 341, 32))
        self.buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(
            QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok
        )
        self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))


def init(self, parent=None):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)

# or
# class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
#    def __init__(self, parent=None):
#        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.setupUi(self)

Dialog = type("Dialog", (QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog), {"__init__": init})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    Dialog().exec_()
```

---

<sub>(1) [Multiple Inheritance](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html#multiple-inheritance)</sub>
<sub>(2) [Cooperative Multi-inheritance](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/pyqt4_differences.html#cooperative-multi-inheritance)</sub>

Comment: But the result of `mro()` looked good to me and I thought that all dependecies between classes were resolved during MRO process.

Comment: @Winand Well that does not happen with Qt, Qt is a bit special with its design unfortunately :-(

Comment: One more new fact for me: PySide's QObject doesn't initialize next super class, unlike PyQt (as shown in `Cooperative Multi-inheritance` article)

Comment: @Winand Each binding is implementing its own methods to be more pythonic (the 2 are still on track) but having a different base (SIP and shiboken) usually have their own limitations, and in that path IMHO PyQt5 is gaining although PySide2 is already updating (only comparing the bugs)